# Getting a 'page not found' when click on nodes

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

My website is showing the list of teasers correctly, but when I want to read more and see the full body text I get the "Page not found" error (I can view the node with the overview of content, but not the node with the content itself). I've been searching through all my settings, permissions etc. and can't find the error. It might have something to do with the view, but I can't see any error there either. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it might be a problem with the path of the view. /node/* is the default path for viewing nodes, but your view has overridden it.